# How to run a excel macro at specific time if you have multiple excel files open

Tags: vba, excel

Hi all and thank you in advance!
I am trying to run a macro in excel who sends emails with a table.
I have tried with:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:00:00"), "Test"

End Sub
```

and it's working, the problem is that if I have multiple files opened in Excel, I will receive an error.
I have tried to put this code in to `ThisWorkbook`, but it is the same problem.

There is a possibility to solve this problem?

Comment: You are calling OnTime from Application, i.e. Excel, so you'll need to specify where the macro is, workbook possible module to.  Look about 1/3 down in this http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Application.OnTime_en.html

Comment: It is possible that your error comes from using activesheet and been working in another sheet/workbook the macro crashes. What error do you see?

Comment: my error is  "Run-time error '9' subscript out of range"

Answer (score 0):

I would use a completely different methodology if I were you.  Take a look at this link.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html

The Windows Task Scheduler is great for these kinds of things.  Open your Excel file with the Task Scheduler and make sure the Excel file has a Workbook_Open event embedded into the ThisWorkbook module.

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/auto-run-macros.htm